How to do matrix transpose using RVV1.0?
Description
I am a newbie in RVV and am rewriting some assembly functions using RVV1.0. Now I have encountered some problems about matrix transposition. Arm NEON provide  the vtrn instructions, helping to do transpose:
# element wide = 8
.macro TRANSPOSE4x4 r0 r1 r2 r3
    vtrn.16         \r0, \r2
    vtrn.16         \r1, \r3
    vtrn.8          \r0, \r1
    vtrn.8          \r2, \r3
.endm

# element wide = 16
.macro TRANSPOSE4x4_16  d0 d1 d2 d3
    vtrn.32     \d0, \d2
    vtrn.32     \d1, \d3
    vtrn.16     \d0, \d1
    vtrn.16     \d2, \d3
.endm

# element wide = 8
.macro TRANSPOSE8x8 r0 r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7
    vtrn.32         \r0, \r4
    vtrn.32         \r1, \r5
    vtrn.32         \r2, \r6
    vtrn.32         \r3, \r7
    vtrn.16         \r0, \r2
    vtrn.16         \r1, \r3
    vtrn.16         \r4, \r6
    vtrn.16         \r5, \r7
    vtrn.8          \r0, \r1
    vtrn.8          \r2, \r3
    vtrn.8          \r4, \r5
    vtrn.8          \r6, \r7
.endm

But in RVV, I do not find instructions like vtrn, why RVV don't provide this? If I have a 4*4 matrix, whose each line are stored in v1, v2, v3, v4 respectively, and SEW=16,   just like
TRANSPOSE4x4_16

in arm NEON, how can I transpose it?
I try to use some methods in this blog, but failed.About transpose shape, 4x4 and 8x8 are needed, and I want to know will the specific implementation be affected by SEW?
Some context
I am rewriting a video codec library named x264, which has a assembly fuction named sub4x4_dct:
.macro SUMSUB_AB sum, diff, a, b
    vadd.s16    \sum,  \a, \b
    vsub.s16    \diff, \a, \b
.endm

.macro DCT_1D d0 d1 d2 d3  d4 d5 d6 d7
    SUMSUB_AB       \d1, \d6, \d5, \d6
    SUMSUB_AB       \d3, \d7, \d4, \d7
    vadd.s16        \d0, \d3, \d1
    vadd.s16        \d4, \d7, \d7
    vadd.s16        \d5, \d6, \d6
    vsub.s16        \d2, \d3, \d1
    vadd.s16        \d1, \d4, \d6
    vsub.s16        \d3, \d7, \d5
.endm

function sub4x4_dct_neon
    mov             r3, #FENC_STRIDE
    mov             ip, #FDEC_STRIDE
    vld1.32         {d0[]}, [r1,:32], r3
    vld1.32         {d1[]}, [r2,:32], ip
    vld1.32         {d2[]}, [r1,:32], r3
    vsubl.u8        q8,  d0,  d1
    vld1.32         {d3[]}, [r2,:32], ip
    vld1.32         {d4[]}, [r1,:32], r3
    vsubl.u8        q9,  d2,  d3
    vld1.32         {d5[]}, [r2,:32], ip
    vld1.32         {d6[]}, [r1,:32], r3
    vsubl.u8        q10, d4,  d5
    vld1.32         {d7[]}, [r2,:32], ip
    vsubl.u8        q11, d6,  d7

    DCT_1D          d0, d1, d2, d3, d16, d18, d20, d22
    TRANSPOSE4x4_16 d0, d1, d2, d3
    DCT_1D          d4, d5, d6, d7, d0, d1, d2, d3
    vst1.64         {d4-d7}, [r0,:128]
    bx              lr
endfunc

and the C implementation is :
// dctcoef : int16_t
// pixel: uint8_t
static inline void pixel_sub_wxh( dctcoef *diff, int i_size,
                                  pixel *pix1, int i_pix1, pixel *pix2, int i_pix2 )
{
    for( int y = 0; y < i_size; y++ )
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < i_size; x++ )
            diff[x + y*i_size] = pix1[x] - pix2[x];
        pix1 += i_pix1;
        pix2 += i_pix2;
    }
}

static void sub4x4_dct( dctcoef dct[16], pixel *pix1, pixel *pix2 )
{
    dctcoef d[16];
    dctcoef tmp[16];

    pixel_sub_wxh( d, 4, pix1, FENC_STRIDE, pix2, FDEC_STRIDE );

    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        int s03 = d[i*4+0] + d[i*4+3];
        int s12 = d[i*4+1] + d[i*4+2];
        int d03 = d[i*4+0] - d[i*4+3];
        int d12 = d[i*4+1] - d[i*4+2];

        tmp[0*4+i] =   s03 +   s12;
        tmp[1*4+i] = 2*d03 +   d12;
        tmp[2*4+i] =   s03 -   s12;
        tmp[3*4+i] =   d03 - 2*d12;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        int s03 = tmp[i*4+0] + tmp[i*4+3];
        int s12 = tmp[i*4+1] + tmp[i*4+2];
        int d03 = tmp[i*4+0] - tmp[i*4+3];
        int d12 = tmp[i*4+1] - tmp[i*4+2];

        dct[i*4+0] =   s03 +   s12;
        dct[i*4+1] = 2*d03 +   d12;
        dct[i*4+2] =   s03 -   s12;
        dct[i*4+3] =   d03 - 2*d12;
    }
}

Here is what I have implemented TRANSPOSE4x4_16 using vslide:
    # TRANSPOSE4x4_16 v24, v25, v26, v27
    lui     t1, 11
    addi    t1, t1, -1366
    vsetivli        zero, 4, e16, m1, tu, mu
    vmv.s.x v0, t1
    lui     t1, 5
    addi    t1, t1, 1365
    vmv.s.x v12, t1
    vmv1r.v v15, v24
    vslideup.vi     v15, v25, 1, v0.t
    vmv1r.v v14, v26
    vslideup.vi     v14, v27, 1, v0.t
    vmv1r.v v0, v12
    vslidedown.vi   v25, v24, 1, v0.t
    vslidedown.vi   v27, v26, 1, v0.t
    vmv1r.v v12, v15
    vslideup.vi     v12, v14, 2
    vmv1r.v v13, v25
    vslideup.vi     v13, v27, 2
    vsetivli        zero, 2, e16, m1, tu, ma
    vslidedown.vi   v14, v15, 2
    vslidedown.vi   v27, v25, 2
    vmv1r.v v15, v27
    vmv1r.v v24, v12
    ....
    ....
      
    ret
endfunc

I finally got the wrong answer.I found I got something misunderstood with arm regesters, and I am fixing it.

I'll have time to answer properly later, but in the mean time, could you share in what context you need to transpose matrices? I'm asking because I'm not sure if need to do it in vector registers, or from memory. Also what sizes are relevant to you? E.g. a 4x4 solution would be quite different than NxN. Do you need to transpose one matrix or a lot of matrices?

Sure! I'll update the question with some background description.

Since RVV has a scalable vector length, it's not always possible to get optimal performance with a single implementation when an algorithm has a fixed size restriction.
This is the case for the algorithm in question, as very few implementations dispatch based on VL, and this would cause a VLEN>=128 implementation to do unnecessary work.
When transposing a NxN matrix, you could e.g. load a VLx32 block of elements, and use strided segmented stores to store a transposed version of that block.
That would scalably use the full vector registers on all implementations.
Another good case is, when you need/can transpose a lot of smaller, e.g. 4x4, matrices at once.
Then you could load every nth element of VL matrices into the nth vector register, and switch up the vector register operand of the subsequent operations.
The above approach could work with your sub4x4_dct code, but that would require the calle to behave differently, so I don't think it's possible to use for x264.
I see two three practical options for your usecase:

Using a single LMUL=4 vrgather.vv to permute the elements into place.
The has questionable performance, since current processors have very slow LMUL=4 vrgather.vv implementations (C908,C920). Other processors may not have this drawback.
It also doesn't really fit into your code framework, as you can't set aside a LMUL=4 register with indices, so you'd need to load them from memory every time.

Using segmented a load or store into a scratch buffer. This works great, because you can just use the dctcoef dct[16] as the scratch space.
The dav1d AV1 implementation also uses this approach.

(this was added later) Using zipping the upper and lower half of the matrix twice. Zipping a and b, would mean creating a vector of a0,b0,a1,b1,..., applying this twice is equivalent to transposing all 4x4 matrices stored in a vector register. A zip can be implemented using a vwmaccu.vx and a vwaddu.vv instruction, as suggested by topperc.


I benchmarked the three implementation on the C908, and the vrgather implementation was 3 time slower than the other approaches, and the zip one slightly faster than the segmented load/store approach (vsseg: 0.277785 seconds, vrgather.vv 1.545038 seconds, zip 0.249973 seconds).
Here is the code for transposing a 4x4 matrix of 16-bit elements:
    vsetivli x0, 8, e16, m1, ta, ma
    vwaddu.vv       v2, v0, v1
    vwmaccu.vx      v2, a2, v1
    vwaddu.vv       v0, v2, v3
    vwmaccu.vx      v0, a2, v3

Notice how here the 4x4 matrix is stored in only two vector registers. This assumes a VLEN of 128, and doesn't fit into your surrounding code, so you should probably go for another approach. It also works on up to VLEN=1024 if you set the appropriate fractional LMUL and adding a vslide to move the two halves into separate registers.
Here is how you could implement the TRANSPOSE macros using the segmented load/store:
.macro TRANSPOSE4x4 buf, bstride, v0, v1, v2, v3
    vssseg4e8.v \v0, (\buf), \bstride
    vle8.v \v0, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle8.v \v1, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle8.v \v2, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle8.v \v3, (\buf)
.endm

.macro TRANSPOSE4x4_16 buf, bstride, v0, v1, v2, v3
    vssseg4e16.v \v0, (\buf), \bstride
    vle16.v \v0, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle16.v \v1, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle16.v \v2, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle16.v \v3, (\buf)
.endm

.macro TRANSPOSE8x8 buf, bstride, v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7
    vssseg8e8.v \v0, (\buf), \bstride
    vle8.v \v0, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle8.v \v1, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle8.v \v2, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle8.v \v3, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle8.v \v4, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle8.v \v5, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle8.v \v6, (\buf)
    add \buf, \buf, \bstride
    vle8.v \v7, (\buf)
.endm

Note that bstride needs to be a register that holds the stride in bytes, and buf is destructively written to. You should be able to use a0 for it, but make sure to back it up for the last store.
Here is a quick example I used to test the implementation:
# asm.S
.global trans2
trans2: # a0 = uint16_t buf[16]
    vsetvli t0, x0, e16, m8, tu, mu
    vid.v v0
    vsetivli t0, 4, e16, m1, tu, mu
    mv t0, a0
    li t1, 8
    TRANSPOSE4x4_16 t0, t1, v0, v1, v2, v3
    mv t0, a0
    TRANSPOSE4x4_16 t0, t1, v0, v1, v2, v3
    ret
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint16_t buf[16] = {0};
    void trans2(uint16_t b[16]);
    trans2(buf);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            printf("%02x ", buf[j+i*4]);
        puts("");
    }
    puts("");
}

Two transposes should result in the original value, and as expected the output is the following on a VLEN=128 machine:
00 01 02 03
08 09 0a 0b
10 11 12 13
18 19 1a 1b

Btw, the last line of your sub4x4_dct_rvv should probably be four regular stores, mirroring the four loads at the start.
I'm also not sure if you use the correct vector registers in every computation, they don't seem to match the choices of the NEON code.

Thank you very much for your detailed answer and your kindness, it was very helpful! I'll check my implementation later. Btw,do you know any good RVV examples that are fitable for beginner? Just spec is not enough for me to write good rvv codes, I think I need more practice.

Even though the spec covers all of the topics, I found this video going over every instruction quite useful: https://youtu.be/oTaOd8qr53U
Otherwise, there isn't a lot of RVV code out there. I tend to use the C intrinsics, because it simplifies writing RVV a bit. https://dzaima.github.io/intrinsics-viewer/ is a great resource for that, but I suspect x264 will want handwritten assembly.
dav1d and ffmpeg have some rvv assembly code, otherwise some of my benchmarks here have some more: https://github.com/camel-cdr/rvv-bench/tree/main/bench

I got one more question.If I have a 4x8 matrix being stored in four vectors, with SEW=16, and I want to transpose the left 4x4 matrix and the right 4x4 matrix respectively. In these case segment store seems no longer works, but vtrn still work well, I can still just use the same TRANSPOSE4x4_16 macro by just changing d-vector to q-vector. Dose there have a elegant way to solve this problem? Why RVV do not have it's vtrn instruction?

From the top of my head, you could do that with a vrgather, or via a segmented store, loading it into 8 registers, vslideup and vmerge to combine those back into 4 registers.
The reason there isn't a vtrn instruction in RVV is that you can't really define it to work agnostic to the vector length. segmented load/stores are close to that, but as you saw they don't map 1:1 to your usecase. vrgather gives you full control of permutations but may be slow because of that, especially when crossing lanes.

When you say "you can't really define it to work agnostic to the vector length", what do you mean? In my aspect, it can be designed just as vle8.v/ vle16.v/..., like trn8.vv/ vtrn16.vv/..., the number of affected elements can be flexibly controlled according to different vl set by setvli instruction. Why this op should work agnostic to the vector length?

How would that work though? You have only 32 vector registers but n elements, or do you mean transpose n 4x4 matricies in 4 vector registers? That seems like a very specialized operation, while vrgather already alows you to so this. I don't think an implementation that implements this fast would be much less expensive than one that has a fast lane crossing vrgather.vv

During the process of porting x264, I encountered many vtrn instructions and I am unsure how to elegantly implement them using RVV. The vslide operation tends to be suitable for cases where vl is relatively small; more often, I need to use segment store, but this should assess buffer. And if vrgather can resolve hardware performance issues in the future, how should I use it to replace the vtrn instruction? Where should I place my index? I am considering storing it in memory, but does that mean I need to retrieve the index from memory every time I call vrgather? Wouldn't that be too costly?

Could you provide me with an  handwritten assembly example of how to use the vrgather instruction to implement a 4x4 matrix transpose, if possible? I would like to know how the indices are set up.

Here you go, this transposes all 4x4 matrices in 4 vector registers for any VLEN: https://godbolt.org/z/a97eqad91
I wrote it with intrinsics, but the resulting assembly is essentially what you'd write by hand.
The idea is to set the index for gathering vector N to (i&3)*vl+(i&~3u)+N, where i is the element index obtained by vid.v. It takes 8 LMUL=1 instructions to create the LMUL=4 vector with the indices, but you'd want to put that outside of the hot loop anyway.

Sorry, I only saw your latest comment and missed the one above. Look at how x86 does the transpositions, from what I can tell that also requires a few instructions. If you can't pull the index creation outside of the loop, then I'd leave it in as is. It should schedule quite well. I'd expect the 8 LMUL=1 instructions to take about the same number of cycles as the LMUL=4 vrgather on a good implementation. BTW, looking at the llvm schedular model of the SiFive P670 and XiangShan points towards those having good vrgather implementations, well have to see.

That's great, thanks! I 'll do more research.

Sorry for bothering you, I have encountered another issue. I need to transpose a 4x16 matrix with elements of 16-bit width. I believe that using vrgather is a good choice, so I made the following attempt:
    vsetivli zero, 16, e8, m1, ta, ma
    vid.v       v16
    vand.vi     v17, v16, 3
    vmul.vx     v17, v17, t0
    vand.vi     v16, v16, -4

    vadd.vv     v20, v17, v16
    vadd.vi     v21, v20, 1
    vadd.vi     v22, v20, 2
    vadd.vi     v23, v20, 3
    
    vsetvli zero, zero, e16, m4, ta, ma
    vrgather.vv v16, v4, v20
    vmv.v.v     v4, v16
'''

But it seems doesn't work. Four rows of the matrix are stored in v4, v5, v6, v7. I think this index is always less than 255 so I use vrgather.vv, But the result of vrgather.vv v16, v4, v20 is set v4 and v5 both to zero, why comes to this?

@Noney Did you check that your vector length is >=256, since 16*16=256? I suspect that's the problem with your code. BTW, wouldn't transposing a 4x16 matrix still work with segmented load/store?

Oh yes, my vector length is 128, and my purpose is to support vector length >= 128. I am confused that why I need vector length >= 128? The reason why I choose to use vrgather instead of segmented load/store is this function's arguements do not privide a suited buffer space,  I have to manually protected the data in the space from being destroyed by transpose operation. I think this will lead to additional cost. As you say, vrgather maybe perform well in the future, so I try to use vrgather.

Oh I know why I need vector length >= 256. I will check it, thanks!

Now I can get correct results using vrgather, but also has performance issue. Another reason I do not want to use segmented load/store is when the matrix shape is 4x16, I think I need 16 vectors to store temp data loaded from buffer and combine them using vslides, it is quiet annoying. And there is also some problems in vrgather when the matrix shape become big, for example, 8x16, maybe I need 3 LMUL=8 regester groups to perform the permution, but in real apps, there always not enough suited LMUL=8 regester groups waiting for me.

@Noney I've added another approach to the answer, that is faster then the other on the C908. However it only works on VLEN=128 for the 4x4 16-bit element case, and doesn't integrate well with your surrounding code, so you can probably not use it, it should still be interesting though. For bigger VLEN you'd need to use fractional LMUL instead.

Thanks, I am glad to see another approach. Although It only work on VLEN = 128,  it still worth a lot, cause we may to do some handwrriten asm jobs on some specific VLENs to get best perfermance, as you say, ''RVV has a scalable vector length, it's not always possible to get optimal performance with a single implementation''.  BTW, is this can fit to other shapes? Like   8x8 or 8x16.

@Noney with an extra zip you should get the transpose of an 8x8 matrix. 8x16 doesn't work directly, but if you treat it as two 8x8 matrices, then you can transpose both at once. That could be an intermediate step of transposing a 8x16 matrix, but I havent thought it through yet.

Yeah, It becomes complex and difficult to understand. I still prefer to use instructions like aacrh64's trn1 and trn2.  In my recent hot spot analysis of x264, I found that some of the hottest functions in x264 (satd) make heavy use of trn1 and trn2. I'm not sure if there are improvements to the algorithm that will allow riscv to achieve the same high performance without using similar instructions. Otherwise, riscv will definitely lag behind aarch64 in encoding side.

I implemented a 4x4 matrix transposition using the instructions vrgather_vv, vslideup_vx, and vmerge_vvm. However, the performance was unsatisfactory! It seems that the data swaps between vector registers are quite costly.
